# Browsersync failing with "class not registered" message

Tags: windows

My environment: Windows 8.1, using Chrome Canary as default browser, running Gulp. Before sharing any further details (to keep this question as simple as possible), can anyone give me a hint what is happening here???

[image: screenshot of last few steps]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: do not set Chrome as the default browser if you have the Canary version installed on your computer. Regular and Canary versions of Chrome maintain some hidden relationship, which results with the above described browsersync failure